Running Simultaneous Steps in Drone.io
I am trying to run a Terraform apply step for both a preview and production environment simultaneously within Drone. An issue that I’m running into is if the preview environment (step 1) fails the apply, then the production step (step 2) won’t run. I want both to run no matter what regardless of pass or fail.
Here’s what I have in .drone.yml:
kind: pipeline
name: terraform-apply
trigger:
  branch:
    - main
  event:
    - push

steps:
  - name: preview-environment
    image: alpine/terragrunt
    environment:
      terraform_token:
        from secret: terraform_token
    commands:
      - …
      - terraform init
      - terraform fmt -recursive -check
      - terraform apply

  - name: production-environment
    image: alpine/terragrunt
    environment:
      terraform_token:
        from secret: terraform_token
    commands:
      - …
      - terraform init
      - terraform fmt -recursive -check
      - terraform apply

Another issue I’m having is related to terraform apply itself. We have a policy that all applies have to be approved and have a description within Terraform Cloud. That means I am unable to use terraform apply -auto-approve within Drone. Is it possible to have Drone start the apply process and finish the resolution in TFC? I believe the terraform apply -input=false should work, but I’m getting Error: Cannot confirm apply due to -input=false. Please handle run confirmation in the UI. within Drone. Any idea how to prevent Drone from failing this?
Thank you!
